# RegExp to extract data from a Redmine log file

Tags: python, regex, linux, command-line, redmine

I have a log file with over 1 million lines in it. I'm trying to extract some data from the log based on a specific username.

Log sample:

```
Started POST "/projects/some-project/issues/update_form.js" for 194.176.105.12 at Tue Jun 10 14:58:59 +0200 2014
Processing by IssuesController#update_form as JS
  Parameters: {"issue"=>{"is_private"=>"0", "done_ratio"=>"0", "fixed_version_id"=>"", "tracker_id"=>"2", "assigned_to_id"=>"", "due_date"=>"", "custom_field_values"=>{"12"=>[""], "16"=>[""]}, "subject"=>"", "start_date"=>"", "estimated_hours"=>"", "description"=>"", "status_id"=>"1", "priority_id"=>"2"}, "project_id"=>"barnet-and-chase-farm", "attachments"=>{"screenshot"=>{"name"=>"screenshot", "content"=>"", "description"=>""}}, "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sometoken"}
  Current user: SOME.USERNAME (id=20)
  Rendered issues/_form_custom_fields.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered issues/_attributes.html.erb (397.9ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_screenshot_paste/app/views/issues/_screenshot.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered issues/_form.html.erb (418.6ms)
  Rendered issues/update_form.js.erb (422.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1032.4ms (Views: 406.6ms | ActiveRecord: 22.7ms)
```

The log file has many repeating blocks of the above. The content in the block is variable - i.e. may have different data, different number of lines etc. However all of the blocks start with the string `Started` and end with the string `Completed` - both strings are at Column 1 on a new line, always.

I need to extract only those blocks which contain the string `Current user: SOME.USERNAME`

What is the best way to achieve this? I'm guessing a RegExp will do the trick, but I'm not sure how to write it to achieve the desired result.

I can use linux command line (grep etc) or some software such as Sublime Text or Notepad++ or anything that the community recommends, such as a Python script.

Comment: Is the Redmine API unsuitable for what you're doing? (Not asking to offend, just wondering if you knew about it.) http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?ms)^Started [^\n]*(?:(?!^Completed\b).)*?Current user: SOME\.USERNAME\b.*?^Completed\b[^\n]*
```

---

As a little python snippet you could do something like

```
import sys, re

user= sys.argv[2]
pattern= r'(?ms)^Started [^\n]*(?:(?!^Completed\b).)*?Current user: %s\b.*?^Completed\b[^\n]*'%re.escape(user)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    print '\n'.join(re.findall(pattern, f.read()))
```

and call it as

```
python my_script.py /path/to/log_file.txt SOME.USERNAME
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome solution. It looks like it's working, however it is outputting the results as a single line. How can I preserve the original line breaks when creating the output?  I'm running this using the Python script like: `python my_script.py /path/to/log_file.txt SOME.USERNAME > output.log` ... you might also want to add in the line `import sys, re` to the top of the script to complete the answer. I will then mark it as correct! :)

Comment: @Adam: SO isn't a code writing service, you know? Sigh. Answer updated.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I'm sorry about that. I should have debugged it myself. I also didn't realise I could edit your answer directly. Thanks for the help (it's working perfectly) and I will learn a lesson from your comment - sorry for putting you out!

Comment: @Adam: It's okay, don't worry about it too much. I wouldn't have updated my answer if I really didn't want to; I'm not that desperate for reputation.